# Lazarus using Indy + OpenSSL on OS X results in EIdOSSLCouldNotLoadSSLLibrary

Tags: macos, openssl, indy, lazarus

I am currently using:

- OS X Yosemite 10.10.5
- newest Indy (10.6.2.0, download 2016 March 13 - Indy10_5346.zip)
- Lazarus 1.4.4
- newest openssl

OpenSSL is more specificly:

- openssl-1.0.2g accordingly to home brew cmd line interface
- placed in /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2/lib/
- lib files in above directory are: **libcrypto.10.dylib,
  libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib, libcrypto.dylib, libcrypto.a,
  libssl.1.0.0.dylib, libssl.dylib, libssl.a**

...

I am passing above pah to Indy using idOpenSSLSetLibPath() befoe using Indy.

but I am getting getting error: **EIdOSSLCouldNotLoadSSLLibrary** at:

```
TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Init() -> TIdSSLContext.Create()
...
LoadOpenSSLLibrary() -> IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.Load()
...
Load()
...
hIDCrypto := LoadSSLCryptoLibrary() -> Result := HModule(HackLoad(...))
...
Result := LoadLibrary(HackLoadFileName(ALibName,ALibVersions[I])); // always zero :(
```

Comments

- "GIdOpenSSLPath + SSLCLIB_DLL_name are correct (file extension set correctly by Indy when using "HackLoadFileName" in "LoadLibrary" call)
- Indy tries to iterate/load over following names: **libcrypto, libcrypto.1.0.0, libcrypto.10, libcrypto.1.0.1, libcrypto.1.0.2**

...

*Side question #1:*

- why does homebrew ship openssl **1.0.2g** in a file called
  **libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib** - is it to maximize compability?

...

*Thoughts on possible cause #1:*

Could all this be an issue of Lazarus compiles **32bit** for OS X? And OpenSSL is **64bit**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install openssl like this in command line: **brew install openssl --universal**

This ensure the library works both for 32 and 64 bit apps.

You may need to uninstall first using: brew uninstall openssl